# Init super from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, swift2

Can I to initialise super of my view controller from a storyboard (also as his child), is there a way do it in iOS? 
I have ParentVC and his storyboard scene, and ChildVC with a storyboard scene. When I create instance of ChildVC, outlets of ParentVC are nil.

Comment: Scenes are no inherited, they are individual and self-contained. Your child view controller will have the IBOutlets that are defined in the parent available but you need to assign them from the one scene.